# Obtain reference from keys()

Tags: perl

I have an array :

```
my @y = keys(%{$table->{fields}});
```

I'd like to have the reference of that array :

```
$columns = \@y;
```

Is there a way to do this operation on a single line ?

Comment: That's an array, not a list.

Comment: What @rightføld means is that `@y` is a variable type called array, which is different from a bunch of scalar values, which is a list. `1,2,3,4` is a list, and `keys %{ $table->{fields} }` returns a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can assign `$columns` to anon array reference,

```
my $columns = [ keys %{$table->{fields}} ];
```